# Controlling an Android phone's audio player via the buttons on the headset?

Tags: headset-controls

I am interested in finding documentation about controlling an Android phone's audio player (e.g. play/stop/skip forward 20 seconds) with the buttons on the phone's headset.  Based on my searches this doesn't seem to be a well-documented topic.

Is there another forum in which I should ask this question?

More specifically, I am shopping for a new Android cell phone (I am leaning toward a Moto G Power).  I use my phone as an audio player and would like to buy a phone that:

1. supports the use of the wired headset button(s) for such functions as play/stop/skip forward 30 seconds and;
2. supports the use of an app(s) [1]  that control the cell phone audio player and;
3. Performs 1 & 2 with a wireless headset.

Every few years I find myself looking for information on this topic and never seem to find much that is useful.

Ref.
[1] head set button controller apps such as ...https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.irishin.buttonsremapperhttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flar2.homebutton
OLD-https://beebom.com/5-apps-to-control-and-tweak-your-headset-buttons-in-android/

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! While we probably might help in solving the issue software-based approach, take note device recommendation is off-topic here. You might be interested in our sister site, Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange, but please ensure to follow [their guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/205) to get the best device for your need.

Answer (score 2):

From a hardware perspective, as can be seen [here](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/plug-headset-spec#control-function_mapping), all Android phones with 3.5mm jack are required to support the following functions: play/pause/hook (Short Press), Trigger Assist (Long Press), Next (Double Press). They can optionally also support: volume up/down. I believe that these days all new phones support all of them.

It's then up to each specific application (e.g. a music player) to make use of these capabilities. Here too, I also believe that most of them do. Of course you also need your headphones to come with the relevant buttons.